# How to classify the thrown exception and calculate the count

Tags: java, exception

We have a piece of code which capture all type of exceptions and I want to classify them based on the exception type and calculate the frequency of each type of exception. I search around and didn't find a good solution to do it. Is there any known technology or library we can rely on?

Comment: Since you are capturing all type of exceptions you can have counters for each exception and increase the respective counter when the exception occurs.

Comment: The complexity is the exceptions are nested exceptions in the most time and the depth of the stack trace varies. I wonder if there is a general guideline or principle about how to count the frequency like should I count them on each level? Or I can flat them and then count

Comment: Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) may be an option here;
Google "AOP exception handling" to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Use the exceptions' classes as the keys in a Map, where the associated value is the frequency count:

```
Map<Class, Integer> excFreqs = new HashMap<>();
try {
    // ... code that will throw all kinds of Exceptions
} catch (Exception ex){
    excFreqs.put(ex.getClass(), excFreqs.getOrDefault(ex.getClass(), 0));
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the solution. But it does not address my concern in the comment of the question.